# UK Google Maps Postcode Boundaries Overlay

Tags: .net, maps, overlay, postal-code

I want to do some geographical visualisations as part of a .net web app. I am quite open to non Google solutions. I'd like to show concentrations of customers. There are lots of customers so I don't want to use pins. I was thinking of colorcoded postcode areas. Can anyone suggest any legal and preferably free way of doing this. The boundaries don't need to be postcode but I think that would be the best fit.

Cheers, Chris.

Answer (score 2):

If volume of pins is the problem then you could group the customer data before passing it to google maps. You can get lat/long centroids for each postcode area/sector/district from a number of sources, but here's one example:

http://postcodepal.com/?page=database-generator

Answer (score 0):

www.boundaries-io.com

very simple REST API for this..includes postal sector,district and wards as well..all results are In GeoJson!